# error class method '+spriteWithFile:rect' not found (return type defaults to 'id') cocos2d error

Tags: facebook, cocos2d-iphone, class-method

using cocos2d framework and received the above error message and was not able to load target sprites.  I am using the code below.

```
-(void)addTarget {
CCSprite *target = [CCSprite spriteWitheFile:@"Target.png" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 27, 40)];
```

the CCSprite line is what is giving the Class method not found error.  Not sure why this is.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo:

```
spriteWitheFile
```

should be:

```
spriteWithFile
```

Also keep in mind that the Target.png filename must use the exact same case (uppercase T) or the file will fail to load on iOS devices.